# New-PSDrive Command : Specified Resource not Found

Tags: powershell, ansible

I just started to work with powershell and not able to figure out this problem. I am invoking powershell csript via Ansible and I am getting error on this command.

```
$password = "Password123" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$username = "am\user"
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($username,$password)

New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\folder -Credential $credential -Persist
```

Now interesting part is, it runs fine alternate times. like first time it runs fine, second time fails and third time again works fine and so on.

Error : The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

Powershell version : 4
Ansible : 2.3.3

Comment: It runs ok every time on powershell ISE.

Answer (score 0):

try to modify to (i think you have an error into your shared path):

```
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\server\folder' -Credential $credential -Persist
```

or try this (other method for build password):

```
$username = "am\user"
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "Password123" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username , $password 
New-PSDrive -Name X -PSProvider FileSystem -Root \\server\folder -Credential $Credential -Persist
```

Comment: No luck..!! Still getting the same error. Tried both approach.

Comment: Have you tried a manual create for verify if you can really create this drive?